# Change python-OpenCV 2 functions to OpenCV 3 function

Tags: python, opencv

Because I failed installation about OpenCV 2.x, I installed OpenCV 3.1 to deployment environment.

But I run the application, everything is wrong.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "main.py", line 25, in 
>      count = bm.dicom_contour_count(im)
>    File "/home/user/workspace/module.py", line 73, in 
>   dicom_contour_count
>      count = count_bone_contour(tmp_path)
>    File "/home/user/workspace/module.py", line 39, in 
>   count_bone_contour
>      orig = cv.LoadImage(path, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LoadImage'

I want to know how to change OpenCV 2.X functions to OpenCV 3.X functions.

The code is below. This code is about finding contours and counting it.

Please help me..

```
orig = cv.LoadImage(path, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
im = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(orig), 8, 1)
cv.CvtColor(orig, im, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

cv.Threshold(im, im, 240, 255, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)
cv.ShowImage("Threshold 1", im)

element = cv.CreateStructuringElementEx(3 * 2 + 1, 3 * 2 + 1, 3, 3, cv.CV_SHAPE_RECT)
cv.MorphologyEx(im, im, None, element, cv.CV_MOP_OPEN)  # Open and close to make appear contours
cv.MorphologyEx(im, im, None, element, cv.CV_MOP_CLOSE)
cv.Threshold(im, im, 240, 255, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv.ShowImage("After MorphologyEx", im)

vals = cv.CloneImage(im)
contours = cv.FindContours(vals, cv.CreateMemStorage(0), cv.CV_RETR_LIST, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, (0, 0))
count = 0

while contours:
    # print contours
    count += 1
    contours = contours.h_next()

return count
```

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: @101 I added error messages. It is related to removed Function in OpenCV 3.

Comment: `LoadImage` should be replaced with `imread`, as implied [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=cvloadimage#imread). A lot of your other functions are also deprecated. Note that the function arguments might also have changed.

Comment: @101 Yes, I know that. But I don't know how to change functions.. :(

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard. The link I posted gives info on the old and updated  cv2 functions (which should be very similar to cv3 functions) so you can compare them directly. E.g. the first line would simply be `orig = cv.imread(path, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)`.

Comment: @101 I solved this problem with your link. Really really appreciate that. Thank you :) Happy new year!